# Determine list of selected partitions on Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-data-hub

When I set the list of active partitions in Data Hub using:

```
select code 
from   systemdivisions 
where  city='Rotterdam'
```

to all customers in Rotterdam, the next queries will retrieve data across all customers.

In Invantive Control I can see in the GUI which partitions are selected, but this is not visible in Data Hub since it is a command line tool.

How can I determine afterwards which companies have been selected as a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
select code
,      label
,      short_name
from   systempartitions@datadictionary 
where  is_selected = true
order
by     code
```

to retrieve the currently selected partitions.

Comment: `select code, label, short_name from systempartitions@datadictionary where is_selected = true`

Gives a more readable output.

Comment: Yes, that is a more nicely laid out column list. I will change answer.